# Error Installing NuGet 1.8

Tags: nuget

NuGet 1.8 seems to have some interesting new features.  Unfortunately when I attempt to update from within Visual Studio, I get the error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: v1
```

I figured I would just install it from outside Visual Studio and see if that works better, but the download link I found

http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases

does not list any downloads for "NuGet Visual Studio extension".

How can I update NuGet?

**Update**

This is on Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio Ultimate 2010SP 1, upgrading from recent NuGet version (how do I check version number?) to NuGet 1.8.

Comment: What's your VS version/OS/Nuget version ? I'll have a look.

Comment: @AlexandreDion same problem here, Windows Vista Enterprise SP2, 32-bit, VS2010 Ultimate SP1.  Uninstall (running as administrator), then reinstall latest worked for me.

Comment: There's known issue when updating from Nuget 1.6 or earlier on VS 2010 SP1, I suggest you uninstall NuGet in VS Extension Manager before installing NuGet.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues#Upgrading_to_latest_NuGet_from_an_older_version_causes_a_signature_verification_error.

Comment: @AlexandreDion fyi, I was going from 1.7 to 1.8, which is how I knew about the uninstall as admin, reinstall trick, I've done it before.

Comment: @tvanfosson right! I missed the last part of your comment. This is then unexpected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the comments, I did the following:

- Closed all instances of Visual Studio
- Started a new instance of Visual Studio as Administrator
- Tools / Extension Manager
- Select NuGet Package Manager
- Click Uninstall (if you're not Administrator, Uninstall is grayed out)
- Restart Visual Studio (still as Administrator)
- Tools / Extension Manager
- Online Gallery
- Install NuGet
- Restarted Visual Studio (this time not as Administrator)
- Resumed work

Comment: it seems that in order to install new version, we need to uninstall the old one first, using 'Ugrade' tab doesn't work (I've just had to do this, from 1.5 to 2.1)

Comment: More recent versions of NuGet seem to upgrade properly, without the extra hurdles.

Comment: J: probably not, in my case it is the latest already (2.1.31002.9028)