# ASP.NET Web API Package Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I succesfully installed the asp.net web api package in my web app.

```
PM> install-package aspnetwebapi
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.

Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.0.20710.0 && < 2.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.6)'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/MVC_4_eula_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.20710.0'.
You are downloading AspNetWebApi from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/MVC_4_eula_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'AspNetWebApi 4.0.20710.0'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.8' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.20710.0' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.20710.0' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.20710.0' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 4.0.20710.0' to ProductConfiguration.
Successfully added 'AspNetWebApi 4.0.20710.0' to ProductConfiguration.
```

When I add a Web API Controller, I get the following:

[image]

and the controller it added is from Web API Beta (with "namespace **.**Controllers")

I'm using VWD 2010.

How do I get this to work properly?

**Edit:**
Can't uninstall...

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: I edited my OP, any more specific info?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using NuGet instead if you haven't already

Comment: There was a notification an update was available. Tried updating but got error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: v1".

Comment: yes uninstall both and try again, perhaps try different versions of both until you have something usable

Comment: I think you need to shut down visual studio first

Comment: OK, ran as admin (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741783/error-installing-nuget-1-8) and uninstalled nuget, web api, reinstalled, nothing doing.

Comment: nuget is such rubbish.  Every time I use it, I regret it.  :(